# PHP - Checking if array index exist or is null

Tags: php, arrays, null, indexing, isset

Is there a way to check if an array index **exists or is null**?
`isset()` doesn't tell you whether the index doesn't exist or exists but is null.
If I do : `isset($array[$index]) || is_null($array[$index])` it won't work because if the index doesn't exist is_null will crash.

How can I check this please? Also is there a way to check only if something exist, no matter if it is set to null or not?

Comment: Wouldn't the same if statements in a nested if structure work fine?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The function [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) can do that, and [property_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) for objects, plus what Vineet1982 said. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated.

Comment: @Asish No one said one should do that. And this question is 8 years old, so obviously things evolve.

Comment: Yes. That is why I mentioned it. And it didn't work in my case. So,..

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2022.  array_key_exists for arrays (not objects), property_exists for objects.

Answer (score 22):

This is the very good question and you can use get_defined_vars() for this:

```
$foo = NULL;
$a = get_defined_vars();

if (array_key_exists('def', $a)) {
   // Should evaluate to FALSE
 }; 

if (array_key_exists('foo', $a)) {
   // Should evaluate to TRUE
};
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: Ok but add the array_key_exist thing in it then

Answer (score 11):

Simplest defined in:
**http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php**

```
<?php
$array=array('raja'=>'value', 'john'=>'value2');
$var='raja';
echo array_key_exists($var, $array);
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$array=array('raja'=>'value', 'john'=>'value2');

echo isset($array['raja']) ? "exists" : "does not exist";
?>
//Output: exists
```